# invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: django

In the view, I get the error message: `invalid literal for int() with base 10`

**views.py**

```
author_id = request.POST.get('id_author')
input_author= Engineer.objects.get(id=author_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

The items in the `POST` dictionary are strings by default. You must convert them to integers using the `int` method:

```
author_id = int(request.POST.get('id_author'))
input_author = Engineer.objects.get(id=author_id)
```